# Precedence Constraints

Tags: ssis

I have created a package to pull a excel file from FTP using FTP Task and then process the Excel file to SQL Database. After pulling from FTP, the excel will be stored in a folder. And I have stored the File path in a variable, and had given a condition in the Precedence costraint, to check whether the file exists in the folder or not. The excel processing task should be executed only if the file path exists. But it seems that even the file does not exist, the package executes, which will fail. So I wanted to check whether the condition I had given was wrong or not. The condition I had given in the precedence constraint was as follows :

```
@[User::FilePath] != ""
```

where **@[User::FilePath]** contains the file path ie **C:\FTPDestination\FileName.xlsx**

Is the above condition incorrect ? What is the correct condition to be given ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the condition `@[User::FilePath] != ""` doesn't help to validate if the file exist or not. This condition will only check if the string variable **`FilePath`** is an empty string or not.

Here is a possible option that you could use to achieve your requirements. You can place a `Foreach loop container` to loop through files in a given folder.

1. Configure the SSIS package as shown in screenshot #**1**. Place an `FTP task`, `Foreach loop container` and any tasks can be placed inside the Foreach loop container.
2. Create 4 variables as shown in screenshot #**2**. **FTPPath** contains the path to download the FTP files; **FolderPath** contains the folder to save the files to; **FileExtension** is the files that should be matched to loop through within the Foreach loop container; and FilePath will be the path of each file that will be looped through in Foreach loop container.
3. Configure the `FTP task` as shown in screenshots #**3** and #**4**.
4. Configure the `Foreach loop container` as shown in scrteenshots #**5** and #**6**.
5. Screenshot #**7** when a file is successfully downloaded from FTP to the destination folder.
6. Screenshot #**8** shows when no matching file is found in FTP folder. If you don't want the FTP task to fail when no files are found, then refer my answer in [**this Stack Overflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889603/continue-flow-on-certain-specific-error-in-ssis).

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]